# Which memory and CPU is used then using COM Object Online

Tags: asp.net, excel, com, vb.net-2010

I am currently working on an application which extracts data from a large excel. I am a bit confused then it comes to CPU and memory usage when using a COM Object online. Is it used by the client, or is it the server?

If it is on server then I will continue building a Web Application, I will use Desktop Application otherwise.

So far I am using Desktop Application to speed up the system development.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you can open Task Manager and see that once you initiate the processing there's some specific process on your machine that suddenly starts consuming CPU time and doing lots of IO accesses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Almost all COM objects used via the web at this point are on the server. I suppose it's still possible to use activex controls with IE but there are numerous security issues & only IE supports them, so it will be being used on the server.

You will have to monitor your resources to see how it affects CPU & ram, but unless it's very badly written or very intensive processing you should be fine.